# How to tell, using Perl, if a windows service is stalled, but still running

Tags: windows, perl, windows-services

I have a problem that probably is not unique, but certainly does not seem to be widely reported.

I need a method to ping a windows service that will tell me if it has stalled out, even if windows is reporting that it is running.

I would prefer to use have a Perl solution but would accept any solution that someone can come up with.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: is Jeremy Petzold related to Charles Petzold?  If so, I'd ask him.

Comment: No, Unfortunately I am not related to Charles Petzold... If I was Doors would open a lot easier for me professionally :-)

Answer (score 1):

What service are you dealing with?  I don't think there is any generic solution to your question if the Services control panel doesn't indicate a problem.  In order to detect a running-but-no-longer-functioning-properly process, you have to know what "functioning properly" looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Win32::Service module

```
use Win32::Service;
GetStatus(hostName, serviceName, status);
```

From http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Service:
Get the status of a service. The third argument must be a hash reference that will be populated with entries corresponding to the SERVICE_STATUS structure of the Win32 API. See the Win32 Platform SDK documentation for details of this structure. You can even grab the service with GetServices(hostName, hashref).

Comment: yeah, I am already doing all that. Not much good if the service is reporting as started in the admin tools but is actually not doing anything.

I think I have a way around this. Websphere pluglet that is running returns a string when you hit it with an HTTP request so I can just check against that to see if it is actually running.